# Use the mediarecorder to enter the audio pronounced in a string

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

Somebody help me with an example of code that takes audio input through the media recorder, and translates it into a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two nice tutorial on audio recording using MediaRecorder:

---

[Tutorial 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)

---

But I think you are talking about **Speech-to-Text** or **Voice Recognition**, which converts Audio Speech to String. If so, Here are some nice tutorials:

---

[Voice Recognition](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/)

[Voice Recognition API Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html)